# (Unique) OR (unique + nontrivial) prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I just wanted to confirm the following: when a text says a ring has a "unique prime ideal", does it really mean "unique **nontrivial** prime ideal", because 0 is a prime ideal, correct? I am writing this after seeing the following the exercise:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, let $M$ be a maximal ideal of $R$, and let $n$ a positive integer. Prove $R/M^{n}$ has a unique prime ideal, so that, in particular, $R/M^n$ is a local ring.

I believe "nontrivial" was intended, because a local ring is, by definition, one that has a unique maximal ideal. Since any proper ideal of a ring is contained in a maximal ideal and any maximal ideal is prime, this is how we arrive at "unique prime ideal $\Rightarrow$ unique maximal ideal $\Rightarrow$ the ring is local" Is this right?

Comment: $0$ is prime ideal? That is not always true, it is enough to take a ring that is not a domain of integrity.

Comment: @Zaragosa Does "domain of integrity" mean "integral domain"? And in the case of the problem, 0 is prime ideal, because the ring R is commutative with 1?

Comment: I mean this, let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Then an ideal $p$ is prime iff $R/p$ is an integral domain. In your case, $0$ is prime iff $R/0\cong R$ is an integral domain. Which means that $0$ is not always a prime ideal.

Comment: @Zaragosa Oh I see... so in the case of my problem, $R/M^n$ might have a unique prime ideal, say $I$, where $0$ is not a prime ideal, and my chain of thought in the last sentence is still correct? Thank you.

Comment: hi abeliangrape; I see that you have asked a number of questions on the site, and received many nice answers, but have not accepted any. are you familiar with the site's feature of "accepting" answers? if not, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) is an explanation of how to do it. if your question has been resolved by someone, accepting their answer lets you both express your gratitude to them and takes your question off of the unanswered queue.

Comment: Yes, since every maximal ideal is prime, if you suppose that your ring has two maximal ideals (at least) then you have two prime ideals which is a contradiction, therefore your ring is local.

Comment: Hello @AtticusStonestrom, I am sorry, I was not aware that the person asking the question was the one who could put a green mark next to an answer. I will do that from now on. Thanks for bringing it up to my attention.

Comment: @abeliangrape no problem, my pleasure! :)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I cannot do this for comments, though, right?

Comment: indeed, that's exactly right! perhaps @Zaragosa could be convinced to turn their comment into an answer for this question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collecting the comments, given a commutative ring $R$ with unity, $(0)$ is a prime ideal if and only if the ring $R$ is actually an integral domain. This given that
$$
\text{Then an ideal }p\text{ is prime iff }R/p\text{ is an integral domain.}
$$
In your case, $(0)$ is prime iff $R/(0)\cong R$ is an integral domain. But despite this, your final conclusion is still true since every maximal ideal is prime, if you suppose that your ring has two maximal ideals (at least) then you have two prime ideals which is a contradiction, therefore your ring is local